# How to integrate intro.js with angular2 cli?

Tags: angular, intro.js

EXCEPTION:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'introJs' of undefined
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'introJs' of undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific [when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far? / What do you expect? / What error do you get?

Comment: link contains total integration of introjs https://belanki.com/programming/angular/angular-7-6-8-adding-walk-through-introduction-tour-plugin-for-step-by-step-tutorial-in-angular-678/

Answer (score 2):

1. Using npm `npm install intro.js --save`
2. Add introjs css style in your project

   `"styles": [
     "styles.css",
     "./node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
    ]`
3. In template file:

   ```
   <div id="tool1">Place to show first tooltip</div>
   <div id="tool2">Place to show second tooltip</div>
   <button (click)="startTour()">Start Tour</button>
   ```
4. In component first import introjs
       `var introJS=require('intro.js')`
5. Then define `startTour()` method

   ```
   startTour(){
    var intro:any = introJS.introJs();
    intro.setOptions({
     steps: [
      {
       element: '#tool1',
       intro: 'Input tool will be used to bring in the Weekly Store Traffic data that was created in the data preparation workflow.',
       position: 'left'
      },
      {
       element: '#tool2',
       intro: 'Enter <code>.\\Supporting_Macros\\Data\\Weekly_Store_Traffic.yxdb</code> within the <b>Connect a File or Database</b> dialog<br><img src="img/configs/config1.png"><br>Leave <b>Options</b> section as defaults',
       position: 'right'
      }
     ],
     showBullets: true,
     showButtons: true,
     exitOnOverlayClick: false,
     keyboardNavigation: true,
     });
    intro.start();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using requirejs the following worked for me:

in .angular-cli.json add .js & .css files into project:

```
styles: [
  "../node_modules/intro.js/minified/introjs.min.css"
]

scripts: [
  "../node_modules/intro.js/intro.js"
]
```

add this in your imports:

```
import { CommonService } from '../../shared-module/services/common.service'; 
declare var introJs:any;
```

finally add something like this when your content has loaded, I had to add a setTimeout for a few hundred milliseconds to allow DOM rendering before running intro.js:

```
showIntro(){
    var intro:any = introJs();
    intro.setOptions({
      steps: [
        {
          element: '#matNewBidsCardTitles',
          intro: "This is a test",
          position: "right"
        },
        {
          element: '.results-save-bid',
          intro: 'Save a bid',
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        {
          element: '.results-bid-score',
          intro: 'Step <i>two</i> description',
          position: 'right'
        }],
      showBullets: true,
      showButtons: true,
      exitOnOverlayClick: false,
      keyboardNavigation: true,
    });
    intro.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Install intro.js using

```
yarn add intro.js
```

or

```
npm install --save intro.js
```

Add css in angular.json

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
]
```

JS

```
"scripts": [
     "node_modules/intro.js/intro.js"
]
```

and now in ts file

```
 import * as introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js';
```

This worked for me. For other [solutions](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/701)

Answer (score 0):

For Angular2+

**Step 1: Add IntroJs in Angular Project****

npm install intro.js @types/intro.js --save

**Step2: Include IntroJs CSS and js library in angular.json(.angular-cli.json)**

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/intro.js/intro.js"
            ],
```

**Note:** To make demo UI look good we have added bootstrap.css (Optional) in the **index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

We are done with integration on introJS in the project.

**Step 3:
Implementation in App Component(or any parent component)**

Now we will get to know How to use IntroJS in Angular Component?

Open the **app.component.ts file, then include introJs as shown below**

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js'; // importing introjs library

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  introJS = introJs(); // assigning it to variable

  constructor() {
    // write the content that should be render in each panel
    this.introJS.setOptions({ 
      steps: [
        { 
          intro: "Hello world!"
        },
        {
          element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
          intro: "This is a tooltip."
        },
        {
          element: document.querySelectorAll('#step2')[0],
          intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
          position: 'right'
        },
        {
          element: '#step3',
          intro: 'More features, more fun.',
          position: 'left'
        },
        {
          element: '#step4',
          intro: "Another step.",
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        {
          element: '#step5',
          intro: 'Get it, use it.'
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.introJS.start(); // Start introjs tour
  }

}
```

Note:  Refer to this link for HTML attributes

https://introjs.com/docs/intro/attributes

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem of importing

> My Angular version is 12

And I use introjs with `"intro.js" version: "^6.0.0".`
And I tried different methods to import, but it didn't work
But this method worked well for me

```
declare var introJs: any;
```